# FFTW exports wisdom file but cannot load it

Tags: c++, file, import, signal-processing, fftw

I am trying to achieve better performance for FFTW operations. For that reason I decided to use wisdom files for plan creation, but the problem is that it can't load the plans from wisdom files (exporting wisdoms works well). I tried to export the wisdom to a file and on the next program run to load it backthe wisdom file, but the function always returns 0 for any filename (even for non existing ones). I also tried it with loading from a string but it doesn't work either.

There seem to be similar questions asked here, but none of them are answered or the problem was somewhere else.
So is this a bug from the library, or am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT**
Only for demonstration and to see if the export functions really work:
The code below shows the operation for loading the wisdom from a string using a file for content import (only to show that the content is available in the file):

```
FILE * pfile;
vector<char> buffer;
pfile=fopen("WisdomFile.txt","r");

if(pfile==0)
    cout<<"Could not open file"<<endl;
else
    cout<<"Could open file successfully"<<endl;

long length;

if(pfile)
{
    fseek(pfile,0,SEEK_END);
    length=ftell(pfile);
    fseek(pfile,0,SEEK_SET);
    buffer.assign(length+1,'\0'); //allocate space with the same length as the file
    int n=fread(&buffer[0],1,length,pfile); //read whole file to the buffer
    assert(n==length);
    fclose(pfile);
}
string show_wisdom(buffer);
cout<<show_wisdom<<endl;    //content could be read

int ret=fftwf_import_wisdom_from_string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&buffer[0])); // returns 0 for every filename
buffer.clear();
//... further FFTW code trying to use `FFTW_PATIENT | FFTW_USE_WISDOM_ONLY` ->but never uses the wisdom file
```

The output is the following:

```
    (fftw-3.3.4 fftwf_wisdom #xbedb7e38 #x1ac524dc #x7a69378e #x21629161
  (fftwf_codelet_t2_8 3 #x11048 #x11048 #x0 #xa75017ef #xb6eb4747 #x4bef8a59 #xb03d9427)
  (fftwf_dft_thr_vrank_geq1_register 1 #x11048 #x11048 #x0 #x27a0c32d #x4e3441f9 #xb3fb3f2d #x90ae8374)
  (fftwf_dft_vrank_geq1_register 0 #x11048 #x11048 #x0 #x9be02645 #x53c7643d #xf6cf9608 #xed5460b7)
  (fftwf_dft_r2hc_register 0 #x11048 #x11048 #x0 #x52a71bc4 #x3c83e70d #x942dd977 #xf047f7e9)
  (fftwf_codelet_n1_64 0 #x11448 #x11448 #x0 #x11559ac4 #xea86db86 #xad6ae8e4 #x97f477c6)
  (fftwf_codelet_t1_16 0 #x11048 #x11048 #x0 #x8811820f #xea00b698 #x861ae7ed #x109ec45a)
  (fftwf_rdft_rank0_register 2 #x11048 #x11048 #x0 #x0095ff64 #x86e47338 #x76e9cf55 #x6cde6434)
  (fftwf_codelet_t1_16 1 #x11048 #x11048 #x0 #x29eda2bf #x97038fb2 #x0eddb089 #xafc2b57e)
  (fftwf_dft_indirect_register 0 #x11048 #x11048 #x0 #x1bea55f5 #x48417896 #x04bc4c58 #x571ce0b9)
  (fftwf_dft_thr_vrank_geq1_register 0 #x11048 #x11048 #x0 #x7b53c8cd #xda17faa2 #x220c1322 #x7c207bbd)
)
```

So as shown above the exporting functions seem to work, but importing it as shown in the FFTW tutorial does not seem to have an effect (the program still tries to create a new plan with the FFTW_PATIENT option which takes about 5 minutes.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg sorry I posted a half edited code (I already used it as you mentioned, but "undo" many times as eclipse allowed)

Comment: So is `buffer` a `vector<char>` or a `char*`? If a vector this code won't compile when trying to use `free(buffer)`. You should rather use `buffer.clear()` to clear its content, and you probably want to do this _after_ you call `fftwf_import_wisdom_from_string`.

Comment: @SleuthEye Sorry, for my floppiness. I hope that this time I could explain respectively improve my question properly. The type of the buffer is `vector<char>`. It is only a demonstaration code, to show that the export functions work. But importing it doesn't seem to have an effect, because the program still tries to create a new plan

Comment: Does nobody  have a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having this issue until I noticed that I was using the function [`void fftw_set_timelimit(double seconds)`](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Planner-Flags.html) to limit the total plan creation time. Wisdom generated with this time limit in place couldn't be loaded whereas that generated with the time limit disabled could be loaded. This seems to be the case even if the time limit isn't exceeded.

As your code has been edited, I am unsure if this applies to your specific problem, however others may find this useful.

Answer (score 1):

According to [FFTW's documentation](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Words-of-Wisdom_002dSaving-Plans.html#Words-of-Wisdom_002dSaving-Plans):

> Wisdom is automatically used for any size to which it is applicable, as long as the planner flags are not more “patient” than those with which the wisdom was created.

In other words, if you would like to import wisdom for plans to be created with the `FFTW_PATIENT` flag, wisdom must have been exported for plans created with the same size and with either the `FFTW_PATIENT` or `FFTW_EXHAUSTIVE` flag.

The sequence would then be to first create a plan ahead of time and export the wisdom with:

```
// Might as well use FFTW_EXHAUSTIVE if we can afford it ahead of time
fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(N, in, out, FFTW_EXHAUSTIVE);
fftw_export_wisdom_to_filename("WisdomFile.txt");
```

Finally, the exported wisdom can be imported and used with:

```
if (!fftw_import_wisdom_from_filename("WisdomFile.txt"))
{
  std::cout << "Warning: could not import wisdom file" << std::endl;
}
// plan can now be created with any flags less or equal to 
// FFTW_EXHAUSTIVE used for the exported wisdom.
fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(N, in, out, FFTW_PATIENT);
```

Comment: It still doesn't satisfy the problem. Because I already export a plan with `FFT_PATIENT` and create the plan with `FFTW_PATIENT` respectively `FFTW_PATIENT | FFTW_USE_WISDOM_ONLY`. But I will give it a try for exporting a wisdom file for `FFTW_EXHAUSTIVE` and using it for a plan with `FFTW_PATIENT`.
I think that it could be a bug in my FFTW version, so I will also try it with a newer version